# boid dynamics are not rendered with flamenco-worker

Tags: cache, boids

I tried to build a scene with boids following a target object. The target object is animated with rigid body dynamics and collision, rolling down a hill. The boids are emitted at frame 1 and should follow the target object. In preview mode and when rendered in blender directly everything looks good. The dynamics are baked in a disk cache near the blend file.
Then I submitted the job to flamenco-manager on the same computer. Flamenco-worker is also running on the same machine.
The target is rendered correctly but the boids are not shown. I then removed the target object and baked the dynamics for the boids again and submitted the job again. The boid objects are not shown again.
Is there a conflict of boid dynamics with disk cache?

Update: I set up the configuration new and now the rendering in blender and in flamenco worked. The difference I see is I did not name the cache.

Comment: This site can only answers questions about Blender and its built-in addons. It sounds as if your problem may a bug in Flamenco-manager itself so I suggest you report it there. There's a bug report button [here](https://flamenco.blender.org/development/get-involved/).